tailwind does not apply the text color requested on vue js and does not replace it with another lighter color
despite all my tests tailwin does not apply the color requested, even after having changed in the tailwind.config file by applying a text color 500 it applies another one lighter I really don't understand have you also had this problem?
here is my config file tailwind.config
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  important:'#app',
  content: ['./public/index.html', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens:{
        'tablet': '680px',
        'tab-2':'500px',
        'midScreen':'880px',
        'xs':'390px',
        'xs-0':'300',
        'xxl':'1650px,'
      },
      colors: {
        ...colors,
      }
      },

here is the image of the color change
enter image description here
puts this on me
enter image description here
instead of
enter image description here
has anyone ever had a problem to help me thank you
I tried to modify the tailwind config folder without positive results
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  important:'#app',
  content: ['./public/index.html', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens:{
        'tablet': '680px',
        'tab-2':'500px',
        'midScreen':'880px',
        'xs':'390px',
        'xs-0':'300',
        'xxl':'1650px,'
      },
      colors: {
        ...colors,
      }


the overriding CSS is being applied by your "Dark Reader" browser extension.  Disable it to fix your issue.
